# PHP: If MYSQL Result greater than 0, add to array?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MYSQL table with a list of services that user's provide:

The Enum values in these columns can be 0 or 1.
0 represents a service not offered and 1 represents a service offered.

```
Cleaning   Tour Guide    Cooking    Parties
0          1             0          1
```

I am then running the following query In MYSQL to fetch my rows in the table:

```
 <?php $myBio = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM user_data, user_services WHERE user_data.user_id = user_services.user_id AND user_id = $p_id");
    if ($myBio->num_rows > 0) {
    $row = $myBio->fetch_assoc();?>
```

I want to generate a list of the services the user provides (where the service has a value greater than 0) - and separate the list with commas like so:

```
Tour Guide, Parties
```

I am trying to do this by using an array:

```
$os = array(if($row['cleaning'] > 0) { echo 'cleaning';}, if($row['tour'] >0) { echo 'Tour Guide'; });
```

I am trying to use PHP if statements to decipher if a service is 0 or 1 before adding it to my list.

I do not believe it is possible to combine php if statements within an array.

Please can someone show me how I can achieve my desired result? Thanks in advance

Comment: **WARNING**: Whenever possible use **prepared statements** to avoid injecting arbitrary data in your queries and creating [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your database columns have a speaking name, you can do it like this:

```
<?php
    $arrayServices = array();
    $arrayAllServices = array('Cleaning','Tour Guide','Cooking','Parties');
    foreach($arrayAllServices as $service) {
        if($row[$service] > 0) {
            $arrayServices[] = $service;
        }
    }

    $sServices = join(', ', $arrayServices);

    echo $sServices;
```

If the speaking names are different from the column names, you need a second array to look up translations.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`array_keys()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) with the optional search parameter:

```
$services = array_keys($row, 1);
```

Example:

```
$row = [
    'Cleaning'   => 0,
    'Tour Guide' => 1,
    'Cooking'    => 0,
    'Parties'    => 1,
];

$services = array_keys($row, 1);

var_export($services);
```

Result:

```
array (
  0 => 'Tour Guide',
  1 => 'Parties',
)
```

[Demo](https://rextester.com/TUH5271)

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this achieve what you want?

```
$results=array();
if ($row['cleaning']>0) $results[]='Cleaning';
if ($row['tour']>0) $results[]='Tour Guide';
// ...
```

Also, please heed @tadman's comment about prepared statements!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
    $myResults = array();
    $myBio = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM user_data, user_services WHERE user_data.user_id = ? AND user_id = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("ss",$user_services.user_id,$p_id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    if($result->num_rows === 0) exit('No rows');
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
    {
        $tempArray = array();
        $Cleaning = $row['Cleaning'];
        $Tour_Guide = $row['TourGuide'];
        $Cooking = $row['Cooking'];
        $Parties = $row['Parties'];
        if($Cleaning == 1)
            array_push($tempArray,$Cleaning)
        if($Cleaning == 1)
            array_push($tempArray,$Cleaning)
        if($Cooking == 1)
            array_push($tempArray,$Cooking )
        if($Parties == 1)
            array_push($tempArray,$Parties )
        array_push($myResults,$tempArray);
    }
?>
```

You will then get the `myResult` array which will be an array of arrays, you can then loop over the sub arrays to check values and construct the strings you intend to make.